# procedural code, vs oopy code and performance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oop, ios, procedural-programming

I've written a backend app for use with a iOS App. When I started the project, I didnt know OOP at all.

Now half the scripts are classes and I am using a mvc pattern and classes. It sure is easier to reuse my methods now, but now there is alot more going on with each request.

For a backend system that handles pre fabricated (Predictable) requests, is it better "performance-wise" to use basic procedural scripts or use mvc and oop?

I ask as it seems as though much more happens when using mvc and oop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speed Comparisons - Procedural vs. OO in interpreted languages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057/speed-comparisons-procedural-vs-oo-in-interpreted-languages)

Comment: I would argue most "OO" code is procedural code hiding in some fashion of "objects" ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hand-crafted solution written in assembly language for the target CPU by expert programmers will perform best in general, but cost 100 times more. Your solution, while it may perform a little less than a procedural program will be far more maintainable over time, allowing you to a) do something else and b) buy faster hardware. Since these are pre-fab queries, add a caching layer such as memcached.